# PHP strrchr find the next to the last not the last ocurrence

Tags: php, substr

I was using the **strrchr** PHP function with **substr** and **strrpos** to find the file name in a string with the full path like:

> /images/onepiece.jpg returns
>   onepiece.jpg

but now I need to a function to find not the last "/" but the one next to the last:
**/images/anime/onepiece.jpg** returning **anime/onepiece.jpg** or **/anime/onepiece.jpg**
And as **strrchr - 1** doesn't work, hehehe :), how can I achieve that?

[SOLVED]
Using PHP pathinfo() as @middaparka and @Shakti Singh said, I've change the way I get the image string from the MySQL database. Now it can have subfolders, as was my initial intention.

```
<?php
/*
 * pathinfo() parameters:
 * PATHINFO_DIRNAME = 1
 * PATHINFO_BASENAME = 2
 * PATHINFO_EXTENSION = 4
 * PATHINFO_FILENAME = 8
 * */
    $slash = '/';
    $mainpath = 'store/image/';
    $thumbspath = 'cache/';
    $path = $imgsrow->photo; //gets the string containing the partial path and the name of the file from the database
    $dirname = pathinfo($path, 1); //gets the partial directory string
    $basename = pathinfo($path, 2); //gets the name of the file with the extension
    $extension = pathinfo($path, 4); //gets the extension of the file
    $filename = pathinfo($path, 8); //gets the name of the file
    $dims = '-100x100.'; //string of size of the file to append to the file name
    $image = $mainpath . $path; //mainpath + path is the full string for the original/full size file
    $thumbs = $mainpath . $thumbspath . $dirname . $slash . $filename . $dims . $extension; //string to point to the thumb image generated from the full size file
?>
    <img src="<?= $thumbs; ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?= $row->description; ?>" />
    <br />
    <img src="<?= $image; ?>" width="500" height="500" alt="<?= $row->description; ?>" />
```

Comment: It is an Opencart database, it stores the image name with the with partial path. The image miniatures are saved somewhere else appending a string with the size to each miniature name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, it would be a lot easier to use the [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) or [dirname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) functions to decompose directory paths.

For example:

```
$filename = pathinfo('/images/onepiece.jpg', PATHINFO_BASENAME);
$directory = dirname('/images/onepiece.jpg');
```

You may have to use a mix of these to obtain what you're after but they will at least be OS "safe" (i.e.: will handle both Linux/Linux and Windows path styles).

In terms of the specific problem you have, you should be able to use the following cross-platform solution to get what you need:

```
<?php
    $sourcePath = '/images/anime/onepiece.jpg';

    $filename = pathinfo($sourcePath, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $directories = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, pathinfo($sourcePath, PATHINFO_DIRNAME));

    echo $directories[count($directories) -1] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. I didn't know about those functions. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: @tenshimsm No problems. I updated my answer with some sample code that does what you require - hope this helps. :-)

Comment: **Why the downvote?** Hmm... you have to love people who downvote but don't have the spine to identify themselves or leave a reason. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to split the path into its segments:

```
$segments = explode('/', $path);
```

Then you can use `$segments[count($segments)-1]` to get the last path segment.

And for for last two segments you can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) with [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) to put them back together:

```
$lastTwoSegments = implode('/', array_slice($segments, -2));
```

Comment: +1 Would it be wise to normalize/canonicalize the path first.

Comment: Just think - a minor tweak to use the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant would make this cross-platform. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As it is part of an URI think I won't have OS compatibility problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function

```
pathinfo ($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
```

Comment: -1 In addition to containing a syntax error (you've a stray `]`), PATHINFO_FILENAME will only return the file name component - not the file name + extension as the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, just make a temp string to hold the string you want to find. Find the last occurrence, replace it with something, like x, and then find the new last occurrence, which is the second to last occurrence.